# python sqlalchemy select aliased

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy declarative base, I would like to have a class defined from a select. Maybe I'm confused what is the difference between `sqlalchemy.select()` and `session.query()`... If someone could explain me this like I'm a 3 yo (with Python knowledge).

I have no trouble with simple joins, like

```
class ViewA(Base):
    __select__ = (
            sqlalchemy.select([C1.attr1, C2.attr2, ...],
                from_obj=C1.__table__.join(C2.__table__)
                )
            .where(...)
            )
    __table__ = __select__.alias('view_A')
```

I'm already using this in the project and it works as I expect it. Now, I'm trying to create another view, but with a self join, so I used `orm.aliased()` but it doesn't work, as it says I have

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError:
(ProgrammingError) (1066, "Not unique table/alias: 'history'", None)
```

Here is how i'm trying to create my class:

```
class ViewSummary(Base):
    _H1 = orm.aliased(C1, name='c1')
    _H2 = orm.aliased(C1, name='c2')

    __select__ = (
            sqlalchemy.select([_H1.attr1, _H1.attr2, ...],
                from_obj=(
                    _H1.__table__
                    .outerjoin(_H2.__table__, _H1.id == _H2.id)
                    .join(AnotherClass, _H1.id == AnotherClass.id)
                )
            .where(_H2.field is None)
            )
    __table__ = __select__.alias('view_summary')
```

Am I mistaken the use of `orm.aliased`?

Thanks for your help,
D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aliased` is part of the ORM, but `select` is not - it's a tool to generate SQL but doesn't map objects to rows. Several of the ORM's constructs won't work with `select` and other core constructs.

You can try `_H1 = C1.__table__.alias()` instead (`aliased` is the ORM equivalent of `alias`)